# Python3 beautifulsoup module 'NoneType' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm new to beautifulsoup module and I have a problem. My code is simple. Before all, the site I'm trying to scrape from is [this](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND)
 and I am trying to scrape the price. (The big number two (2) with more of it)

My code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


quote_page = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

price_box = soup.find('div', attr = {'class': 'price'})
price = price_box.text

print(price)
```

The error I get:

```
price = price_box.text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Seems like price_box didn't return a valid element.

Comment: Yes, but the questions is why.

Comment: Well, but I have gotten the price using the find method, with BeautifulSoup, I just forgot how I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a more robust CSS Selector instead of the find methods. Since there is only one `div` element with class `price`, I am guessing this is the right element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.select_one('.price').text
print(price)
```

Comment: Whoop! My bad, really sorry :(

Comment: It works, even though I do not know what this code means, but it works.

Comment: Basically I am selecting an element with that contains class `price`. Look into this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.headers['user-agent'] = (
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/'
    '66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
)

quote_page = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'

page= session.get(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

price_box = soup.find('meta', itemprop="price")

price = float(price_box['content'])

print(price)
```

Comment: Did you use session.headers to make web site does not notice that we are a bot?

Comment: He simply used a different element to pull the price. The fake user agent isn't necessary for this problem.

Comment: Yes, you can also add random user agents + extra fields.

Comment: User agent and another extra fields are best practice for web scraping. Keep in mind.